# How do I vectorize the following function

Tags: python, pandas

```
def get_project_details(pids: list, conn: pymssql._pymssql.Connection) -> dict:
pidq = ",".join([f"'{x}'" for x in pids])
query = f"SELECT * FROM VW_CSMS_PMT_ProjectDetails WHERE Project_Id in ({pidq})"
df = pd.read_sql(
    query,
    con=conn,
    parse_dates=["StartDate", "TargetDate"],
)
out = df.apply(
    lambda x: {
        "id": x["Project_Id"],
        "type": "project",
        "name": x["Project_Name"],
        "start_date": get_date_string(x["StartDate"]),
        "target_date": get_date_string(x["TargetDate"]),
        "estimate": x["EST_HRS"],
        "status": x["status"],
        "timesheet_details": tdp(x["Project_Id"], conn),
        "main_task": get_main_task(x["Project_Id"], conn),
    },
    axis=1,
)

if isinstance(out, pd.core.series.Series):
    out = out.tolist()
else:
    out = None
return out
```

I am trying to make this code faster, as it is taking forever to process, and I was suggested to use vectorization operations which make it much much faster, so any idea on how I should apply that?

Example of Out(sorry its one line but the format is JSON):

```
[{"estimate": "0.00", "id": "AAM31040", "main_task": [{"estimate": "200.00", "id": "CDM01", "name": "CDM01", "start_date": "28-Oct-2020", "status": "Open", "sub_task": [{"estimate": "200.00", "id": "BDM01", "name": "BDM01", "start_date": "28-Oct-2020", "status": "Open", "target_date": "30-Jun-2021", "timesheet_details": {"actual_hours": 16.0, "actual_start_date": "06-Jan-2021", "actual_target_date": "12-Jan-2021", "approved_hours": 16.0}, "type": "subtask"}, {"estimate": "200.00", "id": "BDM02", "name": "BDM02", "start_date": "28-Oct-2020", "status": "Open", "target_date": "30-Jun-2021", "timesheet_details": {"actual_hours": 142.0, "actual_start_date": "05-Jan-2021", "actual_target_date": "07-May-2021", "approved_hours": 136.5}, "type": "subtask"}, {"estimate": "200.00", "id": "BDM03", "name": "BDM03", "start_date": "28-Oct-2020", "status": "Open", "target_date": "30-Jun-2021", "timesheet_details": {"actual_hours": 557.5, "actual_start_date": "04-Jan-2021", "actual_target_date": "06-May-2021", "approved_hours": 541.5}, "type": "subtask"}, {"estimate": "200.00", "id": "BDM04", "name": "BDM04", "start_date": "28-Oct-2020", "status": "Open", "target_date": "30-Jun-2021", "timesheet_details": {"actual_hours": 20.5, "actual_start_date": "05-Jan-2021", "actual_target_date": "09-Mar-2021", "approved_hours": 20.5}, "type": "subtask"}, {"estimate": "200.00", "id": "BDM05", "name": "BDM05", "start_date": "28-Oct-2020", "status": "Open", "target_date": "30-Jun-2021", "timesheet_details": {"actual_hours": 22.0, "actual_start_date": "04-Jan-2021", "actual_target_date": "06-Apr-2021", "approved_hours": 21.0}, "type": "subtask"}, {"estimate": "200.00", "id": "BDM06", "name": "BDM06", "start_date": "28-Oct-2020", "status": "Open", "target_date": "30-Jun-2021", "timesheet_details": {"actual_hours": 13.5, "actual_start_date": "07-Jan-2021", "actual_target_date": "09-Feb-2021", "approved_hours": 13.5}, "type": "subtask"}, {"estimate": "200.00", "id": "BDM07", "name": "BDM07", "start_date": "28-Oct-2020", "status": "Open", "target_date": "30-Jun-2021", "timesheet_details": {"actual_hours": 6.0, "actual_start_date": "11-Jan-2021", "actual_target_date": "09-Feb-2021", "approved_hours": 6.0}, "type": "subtask"}, {"estimate": "200.00", "id": "BDM08", "name": "BDM08", "start_date": "28-Oct-2020", "status": "Open", "target_date": "30-Jun-2021", "timesheet_details": {"actual_hours": 1.0, "actual_start_date": "20-Jan-2021", "actual_target_date": "20-Jan-2021", "approved_hours": 1.0}, "type": "subtask"}, {"estimate": "200.00", "id": "BDM09", "name": "BDM09", "start_date": "28-Oct-2020", "status": "Open", "target_date": "30-Jun-2021", "timesheet_details": {"actual_hours": 15.5, "actual_start_date": "06-Jan-2021", "actual_target_date": "08-Feb-2021", "approved_hours": 15.5}, "type": "subtask"}, {"estimate": "200.00", "id": "CDM", "name": "CDM", "start_date": "28-Oct-2020", "status": "Open", "target_date": "30-Jun-2021", "timesheet_details": {"actual_hours": 4.0, "actual_start_date": "12-Jan-2021", "actual_target_date": "29-Mar-2021", "approved_hours": 4.0}, "type": "subtask"}], "target_date": "30-Jun-2021", "timesheet_details": {"actual_hours": 798.0, "actual_start_date": "04-Jan-2021", "actual_target_date": "07-May-2021", "approved_hours": 775.5}, "type": "maintask"}], "name": "Digital Twin Benchmarking Data_EV and ICE Vehicles", "start_date": "28-Oct-2020", "status": "Active", "target_date": "30-Jun-2021", "timesheet_details": {"actual_hours": 798.0, "actual_start_date": "04-Jan-2021", "actual_target_date": "07-May-2021", "approved_hours": 775.5}, "type": "project"}]
```

main_task:

```
def get_main_task(id: str, conn: pymssql._pymssql.Connection) -> dict:
    df = pd.read_sql(
        (
            "SELECT * FROM VW_CSMS_PMT_TaskDetails "
            f"WHERE ProjectID = '{id}' AND TaskType = 'Main Task'"
        ),
        con=conn,
        parse_dates=["StartDate", "EndDate"],
    )
    out = df.apply(
        lambda x: {
            "id": x["TaskCode"],
            "type": "maintask",
            "name": x["TaskCode"],
            "start_date": get_date_string(x["StartDate"]),
            "target_date": get_date_string(x["EndDate"]),
            "estimate": x["EstHours"],
            "status": x["Status"],
            "timesheet_details": tdmt(id, x["TaskCode"], conn),
            "sub_task": get_sub_task(id, x["TaskCode"], conn),
        },
        axis=1,
    )
    if isinstance(out, pd.core.series.Series):
        out = out.tolist()
    else:
        out = None
    return out
```

Comment: The only way you can make a cpu intensive program in Python faster is to start multiple processes.

Comment: I am not too familiar with what you are saying, but are you trying to say I should run the same program at different indices parallelly. So the program would run much faster then?

Comment: Which function takes time? `read_sql` or `apply`?

Comment: ```apply``` @Corralien

Comment: Python works with GIL (Python Global Interpeter lock) to avoid deadlocks and other things, that's why it works only with single thread and that's why your code is not too fast as you wish; like the guy above said: you should use multiprocessing. Theres is a built-in lib called 'multiprocessing' that maybe helps you. And I going to be honest: I never used it because I never needed it but I thought that you should know about this lib.

Comment: Can you give a (small) example of what `df` looks like, and the expected output for `out`? From your post-processing of `out` it looks like you expect a `Series`. Do you have only one row in `df`? Also, what are `tdp`, `get_date_string`, and `get_main_task`? Are those expensive to compute?

Comment: tdp,get_date_string are very simple functions they don't slow things down at all. I have uploaded get_main_task, and get_sub_task is very much the same as get_main_task but doesnt call another big function like get_project_details => main_task. So sub_task is relatively quick too(I can't upload it cuz stack won't let me). I feel like its the apply functions that are taking too much time and there has to be another way.

Comment: Prove it. Show us the timings without the `get_date_string`,`tdp`,`get_main_task` calls. Put in dummy values for those columns if you like.

Comment: Also, the `if isinstance(out, pd.core.series.Series): out = out.tolist() ...` block seems pointless, remove it. The apply always returns you a Series, right? (unless it fails, in which case you get None). So why would you waste time constructing a Series, then send it back to a list?